# How to pass variables to MVC using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript

I am using CodeIgniter, and I am trying to pass my variable in jquery to my controller and then pass it back to my view. ( When I do an `alert(dateclicked);` before the ajax, the right value is shows in the alert. )

View

```
<head>
    < script type = "text/javascript" >
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.test').click(function() {
              var test = $(this).('.val').html();
              $ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                  val: val
                },
                url: '<?php echo site_url('test');?>',
                success: function(result) {
                  alert(test);
                }
              });
            });
              }); 
< /script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not

```
$ajax({
```

its

```
$.ajax({
 ^
```

This should be

```
success: function(result) {
     alert(result); <--- result not dateclicked.  
}
```

**EDIT**

```
$('.link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ajax here
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. When I click on the link, I think it's refreshing the page.

Comment: what is getting alerted??

Comment: Nothing is being alerted, I believe the page is getting refreshed for some reason.

Comment: I added your event.preventDefault(); and the page is no longer refreshing and yes I am clicking on the <a> tag. I tried to add <a href=""  onclick="function()"> and still no luck.

Comment: remove `onclick()`. you have `.click()`.

Comment: its `$.ajax` you have missed `.`

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that, sorry I am new to ajax and jquery. Thank you.